# Why does my TCP connection not provide a response to a message when it works OK in netcat (nc) and telnet?

Tags: python, php, sockets

I am trying to send a message to a socket and read the response back in either PHP or Python. I have tried Telneting into the IP/Port and manually sending a command/receiving a response to verify the server is operating as expected. I have also tried connecting using nc (netcat) and that also works fine. In both cases I get a response immediately after sending a test string.

When I try to code it, I am seemingly able to successfully open a socket and send a message, but there is never a response after sending the test message. I've tried coding it in PHP & Python and the result is the same - nothing seems to be waiting to be read back from the socket. The read just times out with a blank response.

This is an example of what I do with nc to test the connection:

```
$ nc 192.168.85.251 10001
tC <--- I type this, and press enter. 
tRIN. <--- this is the response
```

Here's the Python code I've been using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

HOST = '192.168.85.251'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 10001        # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b'tC\r')
    data = s.recv(1024)

print('Received', repr(data))
```

Here's the equivalent PHP:

```
<?php

  $host="192.168.85.251";
  $port = 10001;
  $payload = "tC" . Chr(10);
  $fp = fsockopen ($host, $port, $errno, $errstr);

 if (!$fp){
        $result = "Error: could not open socket connection";
}

else {
        // write the user string to the socket
        fputs ($fp, $payload);
        socket_set_timeout($fp, 5);
        $feedback = fgets ($fp, 2);
        echo "Returned: ". $feedback  . " END\n";
 }
?>
```

Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> s.sendall(b'tC\r')

This is not what is done with telnet or nc. With these tools either `b'tC\n'` or `b'tC\r\n'` is send but not `b'tC\r'`. Likely the server does not respond since the expected message is not (fully) received.